# Filter dataset according the age range probabilities defined by another dataset

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets. The 'unexposed' dataset is quite a bit larger than the 'exposed' dataset. I want to filter the 'unexposed' dataset so that the `Birth_Year` distribution matches that of the 'exposed' dataset.

For example, if I have 1 individual born in the year 2000 in my exposed dataset, I would want 1 individual born in the year 2000 in my unexposed dataset. If i have 3 individuals born in the year 2001 in my exposed dataset, I want 3 individuals born in the year 2001 in my unexposed dataset.

Here is my exposed dataset:

```
> dput(exposed)
structure(list(Status = c("Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed"), Birth_Year = c("2001", "2001", "2000", "2002", "2001", 
"2005", "2004", "2006", "2006", "1999", "2007")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my unexposed dataset:

```
> dput(unexposed)
structure(list(Status = c("Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", 
"Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", 
"Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", 
"Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", "Unexposed", 
"Unexposed", "Unexposed"), Birth_Year = c(1997L, 2001L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 1999L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2001L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2001L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2000L, 2005L, 2003L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to solve the problem using `dplyr/tidyverse`. The idea is to number each `data.frame` by `Birth_Day` groups, then we simply do an `inner_join` to get the same amount of rows in `unexposed`.

```
library(tidyverse)

unexposed %>% 
  group_by(Birth_Year) %>%  
  mutate(rn=row_number()) %>% 
  inner_join(exposed %>%  
              mutate(Birth_Year = as.numeric(Birth_Year)) %>% 
              group_by(Birth_Year) %>%  
              mutate(rn=row_number()),
            by=c("Birth_Year", "rn"),
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  arrange(Birth_Year) %>% 
  select(Status, Birth_Year)

# A tibble: 7 × 2
# Groups:   Birth_Year [5]
  Status    Birth_Year
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Unexposed       1999
2 Unexposed       2000
3 Unexposed       2001
4 Unexposed       2001
5 Unexposed       2001
6 Unexposed       2004
7 Unexposed       2005
```